# Reading backslash with pdfmanagement and lualatex

Tags: accessibility, tagged-pdf, lualatex-dev, tagpdf

I have using `TeXLive 2023` with `LuaLaTeX Version 1.17.0`. Created PDF file successfully, but when opening the PDF file through `Acrobat Reader` PDF file is reading `backslash`. How to deactivate this?

My MWE is:

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,math},pdfstandard=UA-1,pdfversion=2.0,debug=pdfmanagement,debug={xmp-export=test}}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}

In order to learn a bilingual mapping that connects two embeddings into one space, the mapping matrix $W_{X}$ makes $Y_{t} = W_{X} X_{s}$, we employ an adversarial training to learn the mapping. In particular, the generator $G$ tries to make a mapping matrix to confuse the discriminator. In order to get orthogonal parameterization, we note that transforming the source word embedding into the target, its transpose should also transform the target to the source. The $G$ tries to learn a mapping $W_{X}$ to maximize a source representation $W_{X} X_{s}$ to mapping into a target embedding $Y_{t}$. The discriminator D is a binary classifier which aims to enhance its ability to distinguish $Y_{t}$  and $W_{X} X_{s}$. To achieve this goal, we maximize the ability of the discriminator and minimize the probability of generator.\vspace*{-3pt}
\begin{equation}
score_{L_{s},L_{t}} = ∑_{i=1}^{max length(L_{s},L_{t})} ± CSCL(x_{s}^{i},y_{t}^{j})
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

OR need to change the above LaTeX Commands? Kindly advise.

In the Terminal I have used the below command:

`lualatex-dev test1.tex`

Log Report Screenshot:

[image]

`Compile Issues`:
[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your solution. When I have checked the PDF file in `Adobe Acrobat Reader` with `Read Mode` it's reading `backslash`. I have added `Adobe Acrobat` Screenshot.

Comment: @Balaji Your MWE causes LuaTeX to throw an error. Please swap your font commands for the ones David suggested and the error will be gone. Then try again.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, its says whole document. I have using `lualatex-dev` instead of `lualatex`. Updated the questions.

Comment: @KeksDose: I have checked and says same like `backslash`. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have not used `acrobat pro` and using only `adobe reader`. You can download from `https://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: No David. read is always free and 7 days free trial is convert, edit and e-sign PDF forms. Acrobat Reader is always free for read, Activate read out lout.

Comment: ah you mean it reads the whole document but reads each math section as as "latex formula begin backslash begin math .... backslash end math latex formula ends" ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes. Exactly you are correct. How to avoid this? I have need to read only math sections.

Comment: at the current phase of the tagging project the math is tagged with _latex source_ and also `$ ...$` is equivalent to `\begin{math}..\end{math}` so I think what you hear is by design.  (Your question implied that the whole document was read as the single word backslash)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry for the mis-understanding questions. I have required only display-math, when reading it's says `backslash` and how to solve this?

Comment: there is no documented way to change this at the current stage (note this is all _test phase_ code) Possibly can supply a hook to modify the display math tagging a bit but possibly not, I may look. Currently inline math is announced `backslash begin math` and display math is announced `backslash begin equation`  that is by design and not an error.  Future releases will have more possibilities but this is the first release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your detailed answer and could you please advise how to deactivate `backslash begin equation`?

Comment: as I say, there is no way to do that currently unless someone finds time to modify the test phase code. You are asking for feature extensions

Comment: you can open an issue or a discussion at https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project about how math is/should be read.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have opened an issue <https://github.com/latex3/tagging-project/issues/14> and please advise how to solve this?

Comment: @Balaji Different approach: Why is this important? Tagging math will take some time to develop and maybe you are too early.

Comment: @KeksDose if you are blind, or have a blind student, waiting for the polished interfaces to work in a year or so may not be an option. It's not unreasonable to want to get something to work now, even if that includes patching in some fragile regex in to code that may change at a any time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And I upvoted your solution, of course. But maybe he is up to something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat fragile but something like

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,math},pdfstandard=UA-1,pdfversion=2.0,debug=pdfmanagement,debug={xmp-export=test},uncompress}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter



\def\@kernel@math@begin {
  % space after every token so $abc$" voiced as "a b c" not "ab-ca"
  % \mathrm{thing} voiced as thing
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{((\c{mathrm}|\c{mathit}|\c{text})\{(.*?)\}|(.))\ *}{\3\4\ }\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
  % detokenize so \alpha is 6 characters not one cs token
  \tl_gset:Nx\g__math_grabbed_math_tl{\tl_to_str:V\g__math_grabbed_math_tl}
  % voice _ as sub (space already addded above)
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{\_}{sub}\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
  % voice ^ as sup (space already addded above)
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{\^}{sup}\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
  % lose & (you might want to voice this alignment cell separator but...)
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{\&}{\ }\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
  % voice \cr (which should not have been there) or \\ as newline
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{\x{5c}cr|\x{5c}\x{5c}}{\ newline\ }\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
  % lose \
  \regex_replace_all:nnN{\x{5c}}{\ }\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
  % debug
  \typeout{\meaning\g__math_grabbed_math_tl}
  \tl_gset:Nx\tmpmathcontent
     { 
       \exp_not:V\g__math_grabbed_math_tl
       \space 
    }
  \tagstructbegin{tag=Formula,
    AFinline-o=\tmpmathcontent,
    title-o=\g__math_grabbed_env_tl,
    actualtext=\tmpmathcontent
  }
  \grabaformulapartandstart
}


\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
$\mathrm{thing}+thing + \mathit{thing} + \text{otherthing}$ % voiced as: thing plus t h i n g plus plus thing plus other thing

In order to learn a bilingual mapping that connects two embeddings
into one space, the mapping matrix $W_{X}$ makes $Y_{t} = W_{X}
X_{s}$, we employ an adversarial training to learn the mapping. In
particular, the generator $G$ tries to make a mapping matrix to
confuse the discriminator. In order to get orthogonal
parameterization, we note that transforming the source word embedding
into the target, its transpose should also transform the target to the
source. The $G$ tries to learn a mapping $W_{X}$ to maximize a source
representation $W_{X} X_{s}$ to mapping into a target embedding
$Y_{t}$. The discriminator D is a binary classifier which aims to
enhance its ability to distinguish $Y_{t}$ and $W_{X} X_{s}$. To
achieve this goal, we maximize the ability of the discriminator and
minimize the probability of generator.\vspace*{-3pt}
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{score}_{L_{s},L_{t}} = ∑_{i=1}^{\mathrm{max\ length}(L_{s},L_{t})} ± CSCL(x_{s}^{i},y_{t}^{j})
\end{equation}

align

\begin{align*}
\alpha + \beta &= \gamma\\
  2. α + β &1= γ\\
 & {κ}_{j=1}\\ 
& K^{a+1}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

this does not add the `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` at all, it removes any other `\`  and replaces `_` by `sub` and `^` by `sup` in the AltText read by acrobat.

It reads the initial

`\mathrm{thing}+thing`

as

"thing plus t h i n g"

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148988/discussion-on-answer-by-david-carlisle-reading-backslash-with-pdfmanagement-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.